# Can a turtle variable "logged" for different patches?

Tags: variables, netlogo

```
[ifelse ( random-float 1 < 0.99 ) [                              
  set security-apprehension security-apprehension + 1 ][
  set successful-shoplifts successful-shoplifts + 1 ]
```

The above is from a section of coding related to shoplifter behaviour and shows two turtles-own variables (security-apprehension and successful-shoplifts), one of which will increase and the other remain the same. This can only occur when a turtle is on a certain patch (A store). I would like 'security-apprehension' to resort back to 0 when the turtle is not on that patch and for the score to be 'logged' i.e. go back to what it was previously when the turtle is back on the patch so I can set a criteria to determine whether a shoplifter should be considered a prolific offender to individual stores.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on the output you're after, but here's an attempt that makes use of the `table` extension to build a turtle-specific dictionary to store patch coordinates as a key paired with the security apprehension level of the corresponding patch.

First, the setup:

```
extensions [ table ]
turtles-own [ security-table current-security-apprehension]

to setup 
  ca
  ask n-of 20 patches [ 
    set pcolor green
  ]
  crt 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set security-table table:make
    set current-security-apprehension "NA"
    
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Now, you can have your turtles check if they're at a 'store'. If they are, check if the store already has an associated security apprehension level- if it does not, assign one. Then, query that table to get the appropriate security apprehension level for the current store (more details in comments).

```
to go 
  ask turtles [
    set current-security-apprehension "NA"
    rt random 91 - 45 
    fd 1
    ; If you're at a 'store'
    if [ pcolor ] of patch-here = green [
      ; Use the pxcor-pycor pair in a list as a dictionary
      ; key to store/check security apprehension in a table
      let this-key list pxcor pycor
      ; Check if the store has been visited
      if not table:has-key? security-table this-key [
        ; If not, store the security value for this store
        ; (randomly chosen, in this example- how you set this
        ; depends on your model)
        table:put security-table this-key one-of [ "high" "medium" "low" ]
      ]
      ; Get the security apprehension level for the current patch
      set current-security-apprehension table:get security-table this-key
    ]
    if current-security-apprehension != "NA" [
      show ( word "Security apprehension on " patch-here " is " current-security-apprehension )
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

A modified version of the above as per clarification in comments:

```
extensions [ table ]
turtles-own [ security-table shoplift-table current-security-apprehension]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 20 patches [
    set pcolor green
  ]
  crt 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set security-table table:make
    set shoplift-table table:make
    set current-security-apprehension 0
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    set current-security-apprehension "NA"
    rt random 91 - 45
    fd 1
    ; If you're at a 'store'
    if [ pcolor ] of patch-here = green [
      
      ; Use the pxcor-pycor pair in a list as a dictionary
      ; key to store/check security apprehension in a table
      let this-key list pxcor pycor
      
      ; Check if the store has been visited, add shoplift
      ; and security values as needed
      if not table:has-key? security-table this-key [
        table:put security-table this-key 0
        table:put shoplift-table this-key 0
      ]
      
      ; Try to shoplift- if random value 0-1 is less than
      ; 0.98, count as a success. Otherwise, add one to 
      ; security score
      ifelse random-float 1 < 0.98 [
        ; Increase the current shoplifting value by one
        let cur-shop table:get shoplift-table this-key
        table:put shoplift-table this-key cur-shop + 1
      ] [
        ; Otherwise, increase the security apprehension by 1
        let cur-sec table:get security-table this-key
        table:put security-table this-key cur-sec + 1
        print "Caught you red-handed."
        ; Check if they have been caught here 2 or more times:
        if table:get security-table this-key >= 2 [
          print "CALL THE POLICE!"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Hello Luke. Thank you for your help, but I'm not sure whether this answers my question. I have created a simulation which mimics shoplifter behaviour. Shoplifters will either decide to shoplift before entering a store (lime patches) where they will target a store based on a predetermined store vulnerability characteristics, or go to the nearest lime patch. Once on the patch a turtle will make a decision to shoplift; including if their perception of risk is below 40% and they have not been forever deterred.

Comment: 98% of the time their shoplift is successful (+1 successful-shoplift) otherwise not (+1 security-apprehension). Most shoppers will be deterred from shoplifting again if they are not successful once, however some will still choose to still shoplift. That is important in my simulation is that if a shoplifter is prolific, i.e. they have been caught by store security two times or more, there will be police involvement.

Comment: To simulate this I wish to create a table (or something to include in my coding) where if a turtle has been apprehended by store security at this patch twice, i.e. if store-apprehension for a turtle on this patch >= 2 *decision to call police*

Comment: @ChadBrame - Thanks, this clarification is really helpful and makes it easier to understand what you're after. I do think my approach will do what you need, with some modifications- for example, see the edited answer. If it's still not right, I suggest editing your question above to include the detail that you've provided in your comments here- it will make the clarifications more immediately visible to other users.